# PowerBI Paginated Reports and SSAS, can we avoid datasets?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular, powerbi-paginated-reports

We have a user friendly frontend providing PowerBI Embedded combined with a tabular cube coming from analysis services to enable superfast interaction with the data. This works flawlessly.

PowerBI Embedded comes with a number of limitations, e.g. custom expressions and limitations on formatting tables/matrix visualizations and so we want to provide some users with power user capabilities via PowerBI Paginated Reports.

However we run into a surprise. In PowerBI Paginated Reports we add the datasource connection to analysis services and the model is then loaded just fine. We can select all the fields but somehow we are expected to create a dataset; initially we expected this to be a virtual schema of the full model but in reality it retrieves the entire data from the cube. With millions of rows you can imagine the usability of this construction ....

Is there a way to simply live query the tabular cube with PowerBI Paginated Reports and avoid it from creating a dataset by copying the data?

Comment: Reiterating the answer from David Browne, have you confirmed that it actually extracts all the records as you surmise? In tradition SSRS, a dataset is just a query that is executed at runtime, and you should take pains to ensure that it is adequately parameterised so that you only extract the data you need.

Comment: Correct, we are migrating from SSRS (Report Builder) to a newly build solution. We wanted to provide user friendliness; e.g. provide PowerBI Embedded for non technical users. 

However we also have power users building ridiculously advanced reports, and we still wanted being able to cover those use cases with PowerBI Paginated Report Builder.

Comment: In Report Builder we used to connect to Report Models; which have been deprecated and Microsoft basically promotes tabular cubes as the successor. But indeed, in Report Builder the query is constructed runtime and the data is retrieved from a live connection.

Comment: It appears PowerBI Paginated Reports follows a totally different approach forcing you to preload the data. When you set up the dataset it actually does the following; implying it gets all the data.

EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Person'[Person_BK], 'Person'[PersonLastName], 'Contract'[ContractNumber], 'Contract'[Date_in_service], 'Contract'[Date_out_of_service], FILTER(VALUES('Contract'[ContractStatus]), ('Contract'[ContractStatus] = "Actief")))

Comment: I can tell you that for paginated reports against relational sources, no data is ever preloaded or cached. It certainly runs the dataset at design time to validate it but it never loads that data in like import mode in Power BI. I guess you'd need to test a runtime report to be sure

Comment: We checked. If you add an analysis services source it executes the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS in the designer basically; where it should do a basic JOIN; as a result it preloads the entire dataset. Poorly designed imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a paginated report a "dataset" is simply the result of a query that's available for binding to visuals in your report.  It's a completely different concept from a Power BI "Data Set".  Every time the report needs to be rendered each dataset is queried from its data source.

When retrieving data in a paginated report from AAS or Power BI be sure to use a DAX query that returns a reasonable number of rows, and don't use an MDX query (or a designer that generates an MDX query).

Comment: See also my other comments. Let's say we want a dataset with contracts and persons, on a large population. This now ends up causing a query that retrieves millions of rows when we want to run the report; while in fact the specific data we want to retrieve is millisecond range.

Just because, it first tries to load all those contracts and people records in the dataset, and only then perform the request as configured in the report; using the dataset.

Comment: Write the query to only bring back the data you need.  This is no different than writing a report against SQL Server.  You typically use a GROUP BY query in SQL and SUMMARIZECOLUMNS in DAX.

Comment: Ok thanks, but this basically confirms our suspicions, that PowerBI Paginated Reports is pretty much useless in combination with tabular cubes.

It makes no sense at all to connect to Analysis Services, then having a gorgeous abstraction layer available in your cube but still have to write DAX to create a subset of the data instead of being able to live query the cube (which works perfectly in PowerBI Desktop and Embedded).

Comment: That's the difference between Power BI reports and Paginated Reports.  Power BI reports support interactive analytics over your data model.  Paginated Reports are "old fashioned" fixed-format reports.  They both have their place.